# Spacing in labels of a list

Tags: spacing, lists

I entered the following code in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[[$\Rightarrow$]]necessitiy
\item[[$\Leftarrow$]]sufficiency
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I got this:

[image]

The spacing is not exactly as I desired. I would like the `]`
 to be as close to the arrow as the `[` and I would like a little bit of space between the `]` and the actual item.

Comment: I usually define some macros for the right implication and for the left one (only defined in the `proof` environment). `\limplication`, `\rimplication` or something like that. That way it's easy to change their behavior.

Comment: Don't use a list; starting the paragraph with `($\Rightarrow$)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple: protect the item label with braces:

```
\item[{[$\Leftarrow$]}]
```